# Как изменить ширину картинки при загрузке?

Tags: php, изображения

Как сделать в коде чтобы перед загрузкой изменялась ширина например делалась 400px

код:

```
$unikod = substr(md5(microtime(true)), 0, 20);
            $uploaddir = 'images/user/'; 
            $file = $uploaddir . $unikod.".jpg"; 
            $filenew = $uploaddir . $unikod.".jpg"; 

            $ext = substr($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'],strpos($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'],'.'),strlen($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])-1); 
            $filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png','.JPG','.BMP','.GIF','.PNG','.jpeg','.JPEG');



            if(!in_array($ext,$filetypes)){
                echo "<p>Данный формат файлов не поддерживается</p>";
            }
            else{ 
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $filenew)) { 
                  echo $filenew; 
                } else {
                    echo "error";
                }
```

Comment: После загрузки но перед сохранением?

Comment: да как нибудь, лишь бы не создавалось лишнего файла, например загрузился фал его скрипт изменил в размере и перезаписал. Я просто не могу понять как сделать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']);
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 400);
imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 400, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagejpeg($new_image,$filename,75);
```

Comment: куда это в коде вставить?

Comment: Я не проверял, навскидку написал, вставить можно вместо move_uploaded_file. И для png и gif будут другие функции.